# How do I load BertModel from a custom BertForMaskedLM without randomly initializing weights?

Tags: huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model

I've trained a `BertForMaskedLM` model for a few days, and I've `save_pretrained()` it.

I want to compare encoder vectors from a `BertModel`, with the embeddings from
this newly trained `BertForMaskedLM`.

However, simply using `BertModel.from_pretrained("path/to/new_BertForMaskedLM_model")`
warns me that "You should probably TRAIN this model....".

It seems that `bert.pooler.dense.weight` and `bert.pooler.dense.bias` have been added to the BertModel after removing the LM head, and randomly initialized. I assume this means the output of this current model will be useless.

What do I need to do to compare BertForMaskedLM embeddings (after removing the LM head) with BertModel embeddings?

I just want to compare vectors.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Can you please be more specific? Which embeddings do you want to compare? When you want to compare the last_hidden_states of a sequence, the lack of pooler weights is no issue, as those layers are not called to get the last_hidden_states.

Comment: I would like to compare the model(**input)[1] embeddings from model = BertModel(SAVED_MODEL), where SAVED_MODEL is either "bert-base-cased" or the newly trained BertForMaskedLM.